# Parsing Json with Gson 2.8.2 (deserialization) - why is a String considered to be a Number?

Tags: java, json, string, numbers, gson

Perhaps I miss the most important point in building Java-objects from Json. The Json-text I got is

```
{
  "batchcomplete": "",
  "query": {
    "pages": {
      "736": {
        "pageid": 736,
        "ns": 0,
        "title": "Albert Einstein",
        "contentmodel": "wikitext",
        "pagelanguage": "en",
        "pagelanguagehtmlcode": "en",
        "pagelanguagedir": "ltr",
        "touched": "2017-11-01T06:51:29Z",
        "lastrevid": 807175420,
        "length": 144138
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and I suppose a corresponding Java-object is described by the class

```
public class WikiResponse {

    String batchcomplete;

    HashMap<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<Long, HashMap<String, String>>>> query;

    public WikiResponse() {
        batchcomplete = new String();
        query = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<Long, HashMap<String, String>>>>();
    }

}
```

So I tried to deserialize the Json-text above using Gson

```
Gson g = new Gson();
WikiResponse r = g.fromJson(content.toString(), WikiResponse.class);
```

but I get this stacktrace.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "pageid"
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$11.read(TypeAdapters.java:305)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$11.read(TypeAdapters.java:295)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:186)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:187)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:187)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:922)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:836)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:808)
    at freedbimporter.rebuild.WikipediaQuery.main(WikipediaQuery.java:85)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "pageid"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextLong(JsonReader.java:964)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$11.read(TypeAdapters.java:303)
    ... 17 more
```

Why is pageid regarded to be a number? I reckoned it to be declared some String-key ...

Any help is highly appreciated.

Best regards

Christian

Comment: Seems your map has one redundant nesting level as the `pageid` is being  unsuccessfully interpreted as `Long`.

Answer (score 0):

as you could see here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_datatypes.asp

> Strings in JSON must be written in double quotes.
>
> Numbers in JSON must be an integer or a floating point.

So write your numbers with quotes and you'll get your expected String

Comment: Maybe its usefull to have "real" Java POJO's instead of a Map. This one could help you: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, reading more careful and sticking to POJO just did the trick. Thanks!